# find inactive gameobject by tag in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject which I wish to activate given a certain condition. I gave it a unique tag and I tried using `GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Tag name").` From what I can tell, this method will only find active gameobjects in the scene and not inactive ones.

Is there a method that I can call that will also search inactive gameobjects? (Preferably searching by tag).

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After some research it seems that there is no way to find an inactive gameobject by tag.

solutions exist however to access inactive gameobjects:

1 - Store inactive game objects in an array if you need to reactivate them afterwards (only applies to game objects inactivated at runtime).

2 - Do not deactivate game object, simply deactivate the components you want inactive. If you wish to make the object disappear, deactivate the renderer. If it is a specific script, deactivate that script, etc.

This solution will allow you to still find a game object by its tag name.

Comment: mark it as right, because it is the right answer indeed.

Comment: Sure is right. Can't find inactive object. Must store reference.

Comment: This is wrong. You can get inactive objects. See comment below. RTFM.

Answer (score 3):

Things that can find inactive `gameObjects` :

```
transform.Find() or transform.FindChild()
transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>(true)

Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Component>()
```

Comment: @kleopatra : Sry. ... i'll keep this in mind . :)

Comment: While this can find inactive objects, it won't find objects by Tag, which was what I was actually asking.

Comment: Do not use `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Component>()` unless you know what you're doing. This effects ANYTHING in resources, including prefabs. This means you will make **permanent changes** to your files and anything outside the scene, even after you stop playing.

Comment: DO NOT CLICK ON THAT "find more details" links its domain is gone now spam

Answer (score 1):

FindObjectsOfTypeAll does find inactive, it just may also find prefabs and things you are not looking for, so you have to be careful.

Comment: Yes, and it is very slow