# Find also in inactive gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using

```
GameObject.Find("Name");
```

but it only search in active gameobject is there any option avaiable to search inactive object also.

I want to search the object with name not with tag name.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16169074/1870760

Comment: i guess you should need to read the question again its searching by tag name

Comment: I guess you need to read what I said, I said "related". I would assume that if it can't be found by tag name then good luck doing it through `Find`.

Comment: What the actual problem is? .Find is slow and there should be some coding/style issues if you need to use it (as it means somewhere some time you lost control of your own GO)

Comment: @Mark I want to search some GUI elements on Editor mode in order to enable/disable UI elements i.e., i am find object

Comment: if you read carefully you will notice that the second answer in the link @GillBates posted, is about finding objects by name rather than by tag

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to search for inactive game objects by name using `GameObject.Find`.
You will need to find an alternative solution.

Here are a few simple ways you could find your game object.

1. Assuming the game object has a parent and you have a reference to that you can use [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) as it will return

   `parentGameObject.transform.Find("Name").gameObject;`
2. [`GameObject.FindObjectOfType<T>();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

   **This method is slow and should never be called in `Update`**

   You can find by any component type on your game object so you could use a small scaffold component to enable you to find the object
3. Use [SerializedField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) to create an editor reference

eg

```
[SerializedField]
private GameObject myObject
```

4. If you really need to use Find, have your game object active initially, do some initialisation and store a reference to the gameobject, then make it inactive.